# How to get an array of menu items from the toolbar?

Tags: functions, array, admin-bar

Similar to generating an array of the admin menu/submenu:

```
global $menu;
foreach ( $menu as $group => $item ) {
    echo '<pre>'; print_r( $item ); echo '</pre>';
}
```

How can I get an array of all of the available menu items in the toolbar? I tried using the `global $wp_admin_bar` variable, but that seems to not be the right one.

[image: Toolbar]

The reason why I want to generate this array is to use this in a plugin of mine to provide an option to choose which items to hide from the toolbar, allowing users to customize their settings. Right now, I manually created an array called `$toolbar` to choose the items I want to hide myself:

```
global $wp_admin_bar;
$toolbar = array(
    'wp-logo', // WordPress logo
    'comments', // Comments
    'new-post', // New > Post
    'search' // Search
    );
foreach ( $toolbar as $item ) {
    $wp_admin_bar -> remove_menu( $item );
}
```

---

#### Update [2016-09-16]

I was able to get the entire list by using the following in my plugin settings page:

```
global $wp_admin_bar;
echo '<pre>'; print_r( $wp_admin_bar ); echo '</pre>';
```

It's too long to paste in here, so you can view the entire list on this [Pastebin link](http://pastebin.com/QfSaE5Tk). However, below is a snippet of how it starts. How can I get all of the values that are in `[id] =>` and/or `[parent] =>`? It looks like I would need to go through a few levels of `foreach`?

```
WP_Admin_Bar Object (
    [nodes:WP_Admin_Bar:private] => Array (
            [user-actions] => stdClass Object (
                    [id] => user-actions
                    [title] => 
                    [parent] => my-account
                    [href] => 
                    [meta] => Array (
                            [class] => ab-submenu
                        )

                    [children] => Array (
                            [0] => stdClass Object (
                                    [id] => user-info
                                    [title] => Name
                                    [parent] => user-actions
                                    [href] => http://example.com/wp-admin/profile.php
                                    [meta] => Array (
                                            [tabindex] => -1
                                        )

                                    [children] => Array (
                                        )

                                    [type] => item
                                )

                            [1] => stdClass Object (
                                    [id] => edit-profile
                                    [title] => Edit My Profile
                                    [parent] => user-actions
                                    [href] => http://example.com/wp-admin/profile.php
                                    [meta] => Array (
                                        )

                                    [children] => Array (
                                        )

                                    [type] => item
                                )
and so on...
```

Comment: it's the good object but you may read it before it is filled. try the action `admin_bar_menu` with a very low priority to be sure that every actions have been called

Comment: @mmm May you clarify your last comment? From looking into the `admin_bar_menu` is just the hook. I'm trying to generate a list of all available toolbar menu items in my plugin settings so that that the user can check which ones to hide.

Answer (score 2):

There is an action hook [admin_bar_menu](https://developer.wordpress.org/?s=admin_bar_menu) which will provide you an array of admin bar menu items.

```
add_action('admin_bar_menu', 'get_admin_bar_header_array');

public function get_admin_bar_header_array($admin_bar){

        print_r($admin_bar);

    }
```

:)

Comment: to be sure to have the complete bar, set the lowerest priority : `add_action('admin_bar_menu', 'get_admin_bar_header_array', PHP_INT_MAX);
`

Comment: @mmm Maybe I am doing this incorrectly, but I am using this function in my plugin settings so I can get a list of all the toolbar items, similar to how I got a list of the sidebar menu. When I use your function, nothing prints for me. What am I doing wrong exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Hook into the action `admin_bar_menu`, and fetch the menu items with the method `get_nodes()`, because the item list is private and cannot be accessed directly:

```
add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', function( \WP_Admin_Bar $wp_admin_bar ) {

    $items = $wp_admin_bar->get_nodes();

    if ( ! $items )
        return;

    print '<pre>';

    foreach ( $items as $id => $item )
    {
        print "$id: " . print_r( $item, TRUE ) . "\n";
    }

    print '</pre>';
}, PHP_INT_MAX );
```

Comment: I see. However, when I add this function to my settings page, I still don't see anything show up. Should I be calling this in a particular way? Also is the `\` in the function intentional?

Comment: @EthanJinksO'Sullivan I get the admin bar content dumped. The leading \ marks the dependency as one in the global namespace, because WordPress doesn't use an own namespace, while your code probably does (it should!). I've raised the priority, so you get _all_ items now.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I'm just getting around to your answer now that I have free time to re-approach this so I can put some closure to this question. However, I'm still not seeing the items listed. Does it matter that I am running this function in my plugin's settings page?

Comment: Well, you have to register the callback before the hook is called. Inside of the settings page is way too late.

Comment: I see. Thanks for clarifying that for me, I was able to get the array list of the toolbar which I show in my updated question. Now it's a matter of only showing the value based on the `[id]` or `[parent]`. If it's easier to chat on [The Loop](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6), I'll be online.

Comment: @EthanJinksO'Sullivan Use `$wp_admin_bar->get_nodes();`!